# Generating a timestamp when data is entered in

Tags: sql, datetime, triggers

I am trying to generate a timestamp when someone enters in a new data in one column or cell.
Is it possible to have that trigger when BinLocation is updated or added in?

Date format - MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyziE.png)

Thanks,

Jvang

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I recommend using a computed column.
For example, in SQL-SERVER you can have something like this:
When a record inserted the column `[CreatedTime]  AS (getdate())` will be filled with current date-time.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comment](
    [product_id] [float] NULL,
    [product_title] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [title_en] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [user_id] [float] NULL,
    [likes] [float] NULL,
    [dislikes] [float] NULL,
    [verification_status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [recommend] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [advantages] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [disadvantages] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CreatedTime]  AS (getdate())
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I have a table that I imported from excel. Wouldn't I just create a trigger that says when this cell is populated it will generate this date and time?